# mongo remove/pull grandchild item in deeply nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a deeply nested document of family members

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "children" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "grandChildren": [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "toys": [
                    {
                        "id":1
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "grandChildren": [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "toys": [
                    {
                        "id":1
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I'm told the toys are unique to the grandchildren, which are also unique, etc, but there's a chance they're not and I'd like to make absolutely sure when I remove them I'm only removing them for the specific grandchild of the specific child etc,

I have a query that can pull all toys matching the id I was wondering how I can be more specific and burrow down through the specific parents?

```
db.family.updateOne(
 {"id": "1"}, 
 {"$pull" : 
   { "children.$[].grandChildren.$[].toys" : 
     {"id" : "1"}
   }
 })
```

All help appreciated

Comment: you can use positional filters [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

Comment: @turivishal thanks for replying, I'm having difficulty with this, how would this look in a query? I tried it with { "children.$[grandChild].grandChildren.$[].toys" : 
     {"id" : "1"}
   } and arrayFliters: ["grandChild": {"id" : 1}] but it doesn't seem to match, also how to specify first child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "id": "1"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "children.$[child].grandChildren.$[grandChild].toys": {
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "child.id": "1"
    },
    {
      "grandChild.id": "1"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OjaRTebTyCH)